# Visual Studio Creates a Line Space After a Class Property

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 Preview and facing with this weird issue. I'm not sure if it's an issue or a feature but it puts a space (not a new line) on top of a class or a class property line. But it does not do this while declaring variables etc.

I've been trying to solve this problem for a couple of days but couldn't find anything. It's not something to do with line space (it's set as 1.0).

Here is the screenshot:

[image: Visual Studio 2022]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because of the `Code Lens`. It shows all the references that this `Property` has across the code. It also includes `Classes/Interfaces/Structs` and `Methods/Functions`